# cs50 library not including with main function

Tags: c, ubuntu, cs50

I'm new to ubuntu(running under wsl v1) and also for C. due to connection problems I want to use cs50 library locally. I installed it with provided steps. and after I compile a code with make I found some parts of libary is missing.
WSL version 1
VScode

when compiled with make (`make test`):

makefile

```
cc     test.c   -o test
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGINdbR.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `get_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: test] Error 1
```

when compiled manually (`gcc test.c -o test -lcs50`)
it works correctly.

Please can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: The CS50 course should contain the information needed to build and run the applications. Including telling you what arguments are need to build the programs on the command-line. And if it doesn't, if it assumes that all will build and run through their site, then that's a *major* flaw in the course.

Comment: More specifically for you, you don't *link* with the CS50 library.

Comment: how am I suppose to link cs50.h header file? with make

Comment: This should really be part of each beginners course, but building a C program is done in multiple steps... First you edit the source file. Then you build the source file into an object file, this is where header files are used. Then you *link* the object file with the actual libraries needed, to create the executable program file. The command you run (`cc test.c -o test`) hides the second and third step. The error you get is from the last step, the linking. There is a library file, named either `cs50.lib` or `libcs50.a` depending on system. You need to add that when building.

Comment: So if you're building with GCC (on Linux, or Windows using MinGW) then the command should be `gcc test.c -o test libcs50.a`. That builds the source file `test.c` into the executable `test` (or `test.exe` on Windows) and links with the actual CS50 library.

Comment: thank you very much! and isn there a way to use make without using gcc test.c -o test -lcs50?

Comment: Then you have to actually *write* it somewhere. Like in a `Makefile` (used by `make`), or other build or project system (like e.g. CMake). Learning this is outside the scope of this site, but there are plenty of tutorials for `make` all over the Internet. But as a hint for writing your makefiles, use *implicit rules*.

Comment: Makefile is just a script file. So you can put `gcc test.c -o test -lcs50` in the makefile itself.

Comment: OH! thank you very much. now I understand the situation!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are confusing some things and should get your wording right: Linking means combining different compiled source files or libraries. Headers are not linked. Headers are not libraries. Headers are only C text files that are include into another source file. They are not compiled itself. Instead the source file including the header, is compiled and linked with other files.